# Category specific template in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am including a new template for the layout menu with this in the config.xml :

```
<layouts>
    <new module="page" translate="label">
    <label>Foo</label>
    <template>page/foo.phtml</template>
    <layout_handle>page_foo</layout_handle>
    </new>  
</layouts>
```

This all works fine and then from admin I can go to Category->Custom Design and Foo will be a choice in the dropdown for Page Layout.

My problem lies in the foo.phtml which is in the page directory

In that file the footer for example is included with

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
```

if add another file in the same place as the footer.phtml, say bar.phtml in /page/html/ directory.  Then I would expect to be able to include it the same way.  When I do :

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bar') ?>
```

It does not show up.  I imagine I must have to declare the bar file somewhere in the xml too?  I want the bar file only to be included when someone chooses the foo layout option for a category.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The layout_handle node in your config refers to a node it expects to find inside one of your layout files. You can find examples of the other page layouts in `app/design/base/default/layout/page.xml`. But essentially you're going to want something along the lines of...

```
<layout>
    <page_foo translate="label">
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="core/template" template="some/file.phtml" name="my_block" as="bar" />
        </reference>
    </page_foo>
</layout>
```

Comment: If I add it there will it work as I describe and only show up when the foo layout is manually selected?  Currently everything that is in page.xml is in the default node, do I want to define what you describe in a new node or inside that default?

Comment: Since the code is only specified inside the page_foo node, it's layout updates will only be applied if page_foo is loaded by the system. As I said, looking at the existing page structures is going to give you the best understanding.